# Find all addresses that have interacted with a smart contract using Python

Tags: ether, etherscan, web3.py, smart-contract-wallets

I am trying to find a list of ALL addresses that have interacted with a particular smart contract using Python.

I've tried doing this using the Etherscan API, but so far have not managed to do so. Is there any suggestion/idea on how I could go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by

- Running your own node to get the all blockchain data locally
- Connecting to your node using web3.py
- Iterating through each block and each transaction using `web3.eth.get_block`
- Checking if transaction `to` address is the smart contract address you are interested in

You can also use a third party API service, but because you need to make at least 16M API calls to walk through all blocks it is going to be expensive. Self-hosted approach is more cost-efficient.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is try to follow events triggered by those contract functions that you want to hear from. A glimpse in javascript:

```
const eventListener = async (blockNumber) => {
    try {
        const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(address, ctt.abi, provider)
        const event = await contractIntance.queryFilter('EventName', blockNumber - blockNumberN, blockNumber);
        console.log(event);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

wssProvider.on('block', async (blockNumber) => {
    await eventListener(blockNumber)
})
```

1. You need to know the contract that you want hear from.
2. You need an dedicated rpc maybe because public and shared ones usually have 5k blocks limitation.

Lemme hear from you if this has helped.

Update:

Here:;

```
const event = await contractIntance.queryFilter('EventName', blockNumber - blockNumberN, blockNumber)
```

The second param determines how further in the past you should go to access the transactions.

Comment: Is there a way to perhaps just get the data of the past historical data? I was hoping to stick to Etherscan API

Comment: added an update

Comment: My experience shown it very time consuming and does not fit a production solution. If you are the owner\developer of this contract, you might store such kind of history within the contract and manage it as you would like to. ```Etherscan``` API I haven't tried from my code, but using it also means you can not call your solution truly decentralised as blockchain-like technology promotes because you start relying on 3rd party server.

Comment: Everyone does like this and so do i.